# Sorting datetime; pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a big excel file with a datetime format column which are in strings. The column looks like this:

1. ingezameldop
2. 2022-10-10 15:51:18
3. 2022-10-10 15:56:19

I have found two ways of trying to do this, however they do not work.

First (nice way):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

dagStart = datetime.strptime(str(date.today())+' 06:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
dagEind = datetime.strptime(str(date.today())+' 23:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

data = pd.read_excel('inzamelbestand.xlsx', index_col=9) 

data = data.loc[pd.to_datetime(data['ingezameldop']).dt.time.between(dagStart.time(), dagEind.time())]

data.to_excel("oefenexcel.xlsx")
```

However, this returns me with an excel file identical to the original one. I cant seem to fix this.

Second way (sketchy):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

df = pd.read_excel('inzamelbestand.xlsx', index_col=9) 

# uitfilteren dag van vandaag

dag = str(date.today())
dag1 = dag[8]+dag[9]
vgl = df['ingezameldop']
vgl2 = vgl.str[8]+vgl.str[9]

df = df.loc[vgl2 == dag1]

# uitfilteren vanaf 6 uur 's ochtends 
# str11 str12 = uur 



df.to_excel("oefenexcel.xlsx")
```

This one works for filtering out the exact day. But when I want to filter out the hours it does not. Because I use the same way (getting the 11nd and 12th character from the string) but I cant use logic operators (>=) on strings, so I cant filter out for times >6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify this line of code

```
data = data.loc[pd.to_datetime(data['ingezameldop']).dt.time.between(dagStart.time(), dagEind.time())]
```

as

```
(dagStart.hour, dagStart.minute) <= (data['ingezameldop'].hour, data['ingezameldop'].minute) < (dagEind.hour, dagEind.minute)
```

to get boolean values that are only true for records within the date range.
dagStart, dagEind and data['ingezameldop'] must be in datetime format.

In order to apply it on individual element of the column, wrap it in a function and use apply as follows

```
def filter(ingezameldop, dagStart, dagEind):
    return  (dagStart.hour, dagStart.minute) <= (data['ingezameldop'].hour, data['ingezameldop'].minute) < (dagEind.hour, dagEind.minute)
```

then apply the filter on the column in this way

```
data['filter'] = data['ingezameldop'].apply(filter, dagStart=dagStart, dagEind=dagEind)
```

That will apply the function on individual series element which must be in datetime format

Comment: ``` data = data.loc[(dagStart.hour, dagStart.minute) <= (data['ingezameldop'].hour, data['ingezameldop'].minute) < (dagEind.hour, dagEind.minute)] ``` This does not work, it says that series attribute has no object 'hour'

Comment: i cant seem to fix it

Comment: I would write a function like this
```def filter(ingezameldop, dagStart, dagEind):
    return  (dagStart.hour, dagStart.minute) <= (data['ingezameldop'].hour, data['ingezameldop'].minute) < (dagEind.hour, dagEind.minute)
```
then apply the filter on the column in this way
```
data['filter'] = data['ingezameldop'].apply(filter, dagStart=dagStart, dagEind=dagEind)
```
That will apply the function on individual series element which must be in datetime format

Comment: @olubode you may edit your answer with these additions to make them more readable and accessible as well.